# Make QSettings read file from src directory not build

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to read a config file (that I intend to share) through `QSettings`. However, `QSettings` is reading the file from the build directory where else I want it to read it from the src folder. Is there a way to achieve this without tempering with my local settings since I want to share the config file along with the src folder.

```
QSettings settings(QString("configs/config.ini"), QSettings::IniFormat);
```

Comment: You provide a relative path, which is resolved relative to the current working directory (which, apparently, happens to be the build directory, the way you run the application). So either pass an absolute path to `settings`, or run the application with a different working directory. None of this is specific to `QSettings`, you'd have the same issue if you tried to open the file with `fopen` or `std::ifstream`, say.

Comment: Just add the `config.ini` file as a qresource and then use that. It will do the right thing

Comment: The qresource helped quite fine. Thanks. @Waqar